# java - Graphics2D rendering is too slow?

Tags: java, geometry, render

I was making a class for rectangles that are able to change angle, fill color, line color, line thickness. And the rectangles are to be rendered that way. I decided to do a little check up. During the check, I found out that the rectangles are rendered too slowly. I could see them being rendered from top to bottom. What might be the reason?

**GEdit**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GEdit {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        frame app = new frame();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setSize(1000,1000);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Figure.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public abstract class Figure
{
    public static final int TOPLEFT = 0;
    public static final int TOPCENTER = 1;
    public static final int TOPRIGHT = 2;
    public static final int CENTERLEFT = 3;
    public static final int CENTER = 4;
    public static final int CENTERRIGHT = 5;
    public static final int BOTTOMLEFT = 6;
    public static final int BOTTOMCENTER = 7;
    public static final int BOTTOMRIGHT = 8;

    private boolean fill_able;
    private int fill_option;
    private Color fill_color;
    private int fill_transparency;

    private Color line_color;
    private float line_thickness;
    private int line_transparency;

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private float rotate_angle;

    private boolean width_height_ratio_fixed;

    private Point location;
    private int base;

    public Figure(boolean fill_able,
                  int fill_option,
                  Color fill_color,
                  int fill_transparency,
                  Color line_color,
                  float line_thickness,
                  int line_transparency,
                  int width, int height,
                  float rotate_angle,
                  boolean width_height_ratio_fixed,
                  int x, int y,
                  int base)
    {
        this.fill_able = fill_able;
        this.fill_option = fill_option;
        this.fill_color = fill_color;
        this.fill_transparency = fill_transparency;
        this.line_color = line_color;
        this.line_thickness = line_thickness;
        this.line_transparency = line_transparency;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.rotate_angle = rotate_angle;
        this.width_height_ratio_fixed = width_height_ratio_fixed;
        this.location = new Point(x,y);
        this.base = base;
    }

    public boolean is_fill_able()
    {
        return fill_able;
    }

    public int get_fill_option()
    {
        return fill_option;
    }

    public Color get_fill_color()
    {
        return fill_color;
    }

    public int get_fill_transparency()
    {

        return fill_transparency;
    }

    public Color get_line_color()
    {
        return line_color;
    }

    public float get_line_thickness()
    {
        return line_thickness;
    }

    public int get_line_transparency()
    {
        return line_transparency;
    }

    public int get_width()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public int get_height()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public float get_rotate_angle()
    {
        return rotate_angle;
    }

    public boolean is_width_height_ratio_fixed()
    {
        return width_height_ratio_fixed;
    }

    public Point get_location()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public Point get_render_location()
    {
        int x, y;

        switch(base)
        {
            case TOPLEFT:
                x = location.x;
                y = location.y;
                break;
            case TOPCENTER:
                x = location.x - (int)Math.round(width / 2);
                y = location.y;
                break;
            case TOPRIGHT:
                x = location.x - width;
                y = location.y;
                break;
            case CENTERLEFT:
                x = location.x;
                y = location.y - (int)Math.round(height / 2);
                break;
            case CENTER:
                x = location.x - (int)Math.round(width / 2);
                y = location.y - (int)Math.round(height / 2);
                break;
            case CENTERRIGHT:
                x = location.x - width;
                y = location.y - (int)Math.round(height / 2);
                break;
            case BOTTOMLEFT:
                x = location.x;
                y = location.y - height;
                break;
            case BOTTOMCENTER:
                x = location.x - (int)Math.round(width / 2);
                y = location.y - height;
                break;
            case BOTTOMRIGHT:
                x = location.x - width;
                y = location.y - height;
                break;
            default:
                x = 0; y = 0;
                break;
        }

        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public int get_base()
    {
        return base;
    }

    public void set_fill_option(int option)
    {
        this.fill_option = option;
    }

    public void set_fill_color(Color color)
    {
        this.fill_color = color;
    }

    public void set_fill_transparency(int transparency)
    {
        this.fill_transparency = transparency;
    }

    public void set_line_color(Color color)
    {
        this.line_color = color;
    }

    public void set_line_transparency(int transparency)
    {
        this.line_transparency = transparency;
    }

    public void set_width(int width)
    {
        if(this.width_height_ratio_fixed)
        {
            float ratio = this.height / this.width;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = (int)Math.round(width * ratio);
        }
        else { this.width = width;}
    }

    public void set_height(int height)
    {
        if(this.width_height_ratio_fixed)
        {
            float ratio = this.width / this.height;
            this.height = height;
            this.width = (int)Math.round(height * ratio);
        }
        else{ this.height = height;}
    }

    public void set_rotate_angle(float angle)
    {
        if(angle > 360)
        {
            this.rotate_angle = angle % 360;
        }
        else this.rotate_angle = angle;
    }

    public void set_location(int x, int y)
    {
        this.location.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public void set_location(Point location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void set_base(int base)
    {
        this.base = base;
    }

    abstract public void render(Graphics2D g);
}
```

**Rectangle.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Rectangle extends Figure {

    public Rectangle(Color fill_color, Color line_color, float line_thickness, int width, int height, int x, int y)
    {
        super(true,
                0,
                fill_color,
                255,
                line_color,
                line_thickness,
                255,
                width, height,
                0,
                false,
                x, y,
                TOPLEFT);
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g)
    {
        Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Float(get_width(),get_height(),get_render_location().x,get_render_location().y);

        g.rotate(Math.toRadians(get_rotate_angle()),rectangle.getCenterX(),rectangle.getCenterY());

        if(is_fill_able())
        {
            Color color = new Color(
                    get_fill_color().getRed(),
                    get_fill_color().getGreen(),
                    get_fill_color().getBlue(),
                    get_fill_transparency());
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fill(rectangle);
        }

        Stroke old_stroke = g.getStroke();
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(get_line_thickness()));

        Color line_color = new Color(
                get_line_color().getRed(),
                get_line_color().getGreen(),
                get_line_color().getBlue(),
                get_line_transparency());
        g.setColor(line_color);
        g.draw(rectangle);

        g.setStroke(old_stroke);
        g.rotate(Math.toRadians(get_rotate_angle() * -1),rectangle.getCenterX(),rectangle.getCenterY());
    }
}
```

**frame.java**

```
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class frame extends JFrame{
    public frame()
    {
        super("test");

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)g;

        RenderingHints renderingHints1 = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        RenderingHints renderingHints2 = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHints(renderingHints1);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHints(renderingHints2);

        Random random = new Random();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);

        for(int i =0;i < 10; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Color.CYAN,Color.BLACK,random.nextInt(10),random.nextInt(1000),random.nextInt(1000),random.nextInt(300),random.nextInt(300));
            rectangle.set_fill_transparency(random.nextInt(255));
            rectangle.set_rotate_angle(random.nextInt(180));
            rectangle.render(graphics2D);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't override `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, start with something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method - that way you get double buffering for free.  You may also want to consider not creating new objects on each paint cycle

Comment: It would appear, that all the operations on the shape objects could be done outside of paint

Comment: You also allowing transformation operations to be compounded from one object to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't override paint of top level containers like `JFrame`, start with something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method - that way you get double buffering for free.
- Consider not creating new objects on each paint cycle - this is create a number of short lived objects which can affect performance
- You could perform some of the operations outside of the `paint` method (setting the properties) and just focus on painting the inside the `paint` method
- Remember, transformations (such as `rotate` and `translate`) are compounding, this means they will affect everything painted after them. You either need to take a snapshot of the `Graphics` context before hand and `dispose` of it when you're finished, or reverse the transformations.

You might like to take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works in Swing.

Without changing anything, other then using a `JPanel` and `paintComponent`, it works fine.

I even threw in a Swing `Timer` and repainted the panel at 25fps a second without issue.  And just for fun, I set it to 200fps without issue

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Random random = new Random();

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            RenderingHints renderingHints1 = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            RenderingHints renderingHints2 = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHints(renderingHints1);
            g2d.setRenderingHints(renderingHints2);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Color.CYAN, 
                                Color.BLACK, 
                                random.nextInt(10), 
                                random.nextInt(200), 
                                random.nextInt(200), 
                                random.nextInt(200), random.nextInt(200));
                rectangle.set_fill_transparency(random.nextInt(255));
                rectangle.set_rotate_angle(random.nextInt(180));
                Graphics2D iDontTrustYou = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
                rectangle.render(iDontTrustYou);
                iDontTrustYou.dispose();
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public abstract class Figure {

        public static final int TOPLEFT = 0;
        public static final int TOPCENTER = 1;
        public static final int TOPRIGHT = 2;
        public static final int CENTERLEFT = 3;
        public static final int CENTER = 4;
        public static final int CENTERRIGHT = 5;
        public static final int BOTTOMLEFT = 6;
        public static final int BOTTOMCENTER = 7;
        public static final int BOTTOMRIGHT = 8;

        private boolean fill_able;
        private int fill_option;
        private Color fill_color;
        private int fill_transparency;

        private Color line_color;
        private float line_thickness;
        private int line_transparency;

        private int width;
        private int height;
        private float rotate_angle;

        private boolean width_height_ratio_fixed;

        private Point location;
        private int base;

        public Figure(boolean fill_able,
                        int fill_option,
                        Color fill_color,
                        int fill_transparency,
                        Color line_color,
                        float line_thickness,
                        int line_transparency,
                        int width, int height,
                        float rotate_angle,
                        boolean width_height_ratio_fixed,
                        int x, int y,
                        int base) {
            this.fill_able = fill_able;
            this.fill_option = fill_option;
            this.fill_color = fill_color;
            this.fill_transparency = fill_transparency;
            this.line_color = line_color;
            this.line_thickness = line_thickness;
            this.line_transparency = line_transparency;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.rotate_angle = rotate_angle;
            this.width_height_ratio_fixed = width_height_ratio_fixed;
            this.location = new Point(x, y);
            this.base = base;
        }

        public boolean is_fill_able() {
            return fill_able;
        }

        public int get_fill_option() {
            return fill_option;
        }

        public Color get_fill_color() {
            return fill_color;
        }

        public int get_fill_transparency() {

            return fill_transparency;
        }

        public Color get_line_color() {
            return line_color;
        }

        public float get_line_thickness() {
            return line_thickness;
        }

        public int get_line_transparency() {
            return line_transparency;
        }

        public int get_width() {
            return width;
        }

        public int get_height() {
            return height;
        }

        public float get_rotate_angle() {
            return rotate_angle;
        }

        public boolean is_width_height_ratio_fixed() {
            return width_height_ratio_fixed;
        }

        public Point get_location() {
            return location;
        }

        public Point get_render_location() {
            int x, y;

            switch (base) {
                case TOPLEFT:
                    x = location.x;
                    y = location.y;
                    break;
                case TOPCENTER:
                    x = location.x - (int) Math.round(width / 2);
                    y = location.y;
                    break;
                case TOPRIGHT:
                    x = location.x - width;
                    y = location.y;
                    break;
                case CENTERLEFT:
                    x = location.x;
                    y = location.y - (int) Math.round(height / 2);
                    break;
                case CENTER:
                    x = location.x - (int) Math.round(width / 2);
                    y = location.y - (int) Math.round(height / 2);
                    break;
                case CENTERRIGHT:
                    x = location.x - width;
                    y = location.y - (int) Math.round(height / 2);
                    break;
                case BOTTOMLEFT:
                    x = location.x;
                    y = location.y - height;
                    break;
                case BOTTOMCENTER:
                    x = location.x - (int) Math.round(width / 2);
                    y = location.y - height;
                    break;
                case BOTTOMRIGHT:
                    x = location.x - width;
                    y = location.y - height;
                    break;
                default:
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    break;
            }

            return new Point(x, y);
        }

        public int get_base() {
            return base;
        }

        public void set_fill_option(int option) {
            this.fill_option = option;
        }

        public void set_fill_color(Color color) {
            this.fill_color = color;
        }

        public void set_fill_transparency(int transparency) {
            this.fill_transparency = transparency;
        }

        public void set_line_color(Color color) {
            this.line_color = color;
        }

        public void set_line_transparency(int transparency) {
            this.line_transparency = transparency;
        }

        public void set_width(int width) {
            if (this.width_height_ratio_fixed) {
                float ratio = this.height / this.width;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = (int) Math.round(width * ratio);
            } else {
                this.width = width;
            }
        }

        public void set_height(int height) {
            if (this.width_height_ratio_fixed) {
                float ratio = this.width / this.height;
                this.height = height;
                this.width = (int) Math.round(height * ratio);
            } else {
                this.height = height;
            }
        }

        public void set_rotate_angle(float angle) {
            if (angle > 360) {
                this.rotate_angle = angle % 360;
            } else {
                this.rotate_angle = angle;
            }
        }

        public void set_location(int x, int y) {
            this.location.setLocation(x, y);
        }

        public void set_location(Point location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public void set_base(int base) {
            this.base = base;
        }

        abstract public void render(Graphics2D g);
    }

    public class Rectangle extends Figure {

        public Rectangle(Color fill_color, Color line_color, float line_thickness, int width, int height, int x, int y) {
            super(true,
                            0,
                            fill_color,
                            255,
                            line_color,
                            line_thickness,
                            255,
                            width, height,
                            0,
                            false,
                            x, y,
                            TOPLEFT);
        }

        public void render(Graphics2D g) {
            Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Float(get_width(), get_height(), get_render_location().x, get_render_location().y);

            g.rotate(Math.toRadians(get_rotate_angle()), rectangle.getCenterX(), rectangle.getCenterY());

            if (is_fill_able()) {
                Color color = new Color(
                                get_fill_color().getRed(),
                                get_fill_color().getGreen(),
                                get_fill_color().getBlue(),
                                get_fill_transparency());
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fill(rectangle);
            }

            Stroke old_stroke = g.getStroke();
            g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(get_line_thickness()));

            Color line_color = new Color(
                            get_line_color().getRed(),
                            get_line_color().getGreen(),
                            get_line_color().getBlue(),
                            get_line_transparency());
            g.setColor(line_color);
            g.draw(rectangle);

            g.setStroke(old_stroke);
            g.rotate(Math.toRadians(get_rotate_angle() * -1), rectangle.getCenterX(), rectangle.getCenterY());
        }
    }

}
```

A slightly better optimised version might look something like...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Random random = new Random();

    private List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>(25);

    public TestPane() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Color.CYAN,
                            Color.BLACK,
                            random.nextInt(10),
                            random.nextInt(200),
                            random.nextInt(200),
                            random.nextInt(200), random.nextInt(200));
            rectangle.set_fill_transparency(random.nextInt(255));
            rectangle.set_rotate_angle(random.nextInt(180));
            rectangles.add(rectangle);
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
                    rectangle.set_height(random.nextInt(200));
                    rectangle.set_width(random.nextInt(200));
                    rectangle.set_location(random.nextInt(200), random.nextInt(200));
                    rectangle.set_fill_transparency(random.nextInt(255));
                    rectangle.set_rotate_angle(random.nextInt(180));
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        RenderingHints renderingHints1 = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        RenderingHints renderingHints2 = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(renderingHints1);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(renderingHints2);
        for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
            Graphics2D iDontTrustYou = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            rectangle.render(iDontTrustYou);
            iDontTrustYou.dispose();
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

If you still find that the performance isn't up to what you want, you might consider having a look at [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) which will give you complete control over the painting process

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the method `paint`, which is usually a bad idea.

You are also calculating all the information needed DURING the paint, which is another bad idea: they should be calculated before. If you need 4x10 random numbers, maybe calculate them before the paint and store the 40 numbers in a int[] array.

As someone mentioned, you should want to use a `JPanel` and the method `paintComponent`.

The following link might be an interesting reading for you:
http://www.billharlan.com/papers/Improving_Swing_Performance.html